# how do I create a transparent circle with adjustable radius on a map in openlayers 3

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I am wanting to put a map with certain controls in a html document page, so that visitors can select a distance radius around their location.

One of the controls I need is a semi transparent circle with a line from the centre to the edge.  I want this circle to be adjustable using the mouse from the outer edge and keep its scale and position on the map when zooming or panning...

I am using Django as my back end. I'd also like to know if I'd need to use javascript to accomplish this?

I have decided to use Openlayers 3, but have never used it before today and would like to get this task out of the way so as to understand it better and become more confident so I can build more apps and hopefully help others in the future.

Any brain boxes out there?

EDIT: I have managed to put postcode search form and a map on the page, but am now a little stumped on how to add a circle to the arrangement...

This is what I have so far;

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.12.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
      .map {
        height: 500px;
        width: 80%;
        padding: 10px;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.12.0/build/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>OpenLayers 3 example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>My Map</h2>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'osm'})})
                ],
          view: new ol.View({
          center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([{{ long }}, {{ lat }}]),
          zoom: {{ zoom }}
        })
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am using python-django to parse long, lat and zoom into the code... how would I get a circle to render on the same map centered around the long, lat chords?

If you need more information on how to recreate what I have so far then please let me know what you need and I will be happy to provide it.

Comment: Something like this????? http://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/c6k1Lr46/

Comment: no, I already have something like that, what I need is to be able to adjust it with the mouse from the circumference edge...

Comment: then check this http://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/qL7b3mxL/. Fiddle is a mess but your job is done. Code borrowed from here-->http://viglino.github.io/ol3-ext/examples/map.interaction.transform.html

Comment: wow thank you for that... I appreciate all the work you have put into this but  I am looking for a specific user experience... I want the user to be able to control only the circle from its edge... like the circle in this example http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-features.html?q=circle

the origin needs to stay fixed to the long, lat I give it, and the feature should only become editable when the mouse moves over it (the line and control point need to appear when the mouse hovers over it)
I am not too good at understanding the code so lots of comments would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, OpenLayers only supports mouse-modification for Polygons, [not circles](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/3777#issuecomment-142960593).

I'm sure it is possible to write code that modifies circles, but that code does not exist yet in OpenLayers (as of 3.17.x).

You could create a class like `ol.interaction.Modify`, and make it support circles. See the [source code](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/v3.14.2/src/ol/interaction/modifyinteraction.js) to see how they modify Polygons, and modify it to support Circles.